# Center stack view in popover modal

Tags: swift, uipopovercontroller, uistackview

I'm trying to present a loading bar with a button below it within a popover view controller. I can present the UIProgressView on it's own just fine. I'm working on putting the UIProgressView and a UIButton into a stack view and presenting that in the center of the popover.

I've posted my code below and the resulting view that I get. The stack view is there with a button but it's located at x: -25 y: 0 according to the debugger. I tried setting the stack view center coordinates to the self.view.center coordinates but that didn't work. Is there something I'm not setting correctly?

```
// Collection View #1
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tv = VideoLibrary() // <- Collection View class
    tv.videoSelectionDelegate = self
    tv.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    tv.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    present(tv, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// VideoLibrary() / Collection View #2
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let loadingView = LoadingVideoView() // <- view with stack view
    loadingView.view.frame = self.view.frame
    loadingView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(loadingView, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}


// LoadingVideoView()
var progressView: UIProgressView = {
   let progress = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progress.progress = 0.5
    return progress
}()
var blurView: UIVisualEffectView = {
   let effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: effect)
    return blur
}()
var stack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
    stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stack.axis = .vertical
    stack.alignment = .center
    stack.spacing = 20
    return stack
}()
var cancelButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    button.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.view.insertSubview(blurView, at: 0)
    stack.addArrangedSubview(progressView)
    stack.addArrangedSubview(cancelButton)

    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cancelButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stack.center = self.view.center

    self.view.addSubview(stack)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to set `stack.center = self.view.center` in the `viewDidAppear(...)` function call. At the end of the `viewWillAppear(...)` function, the center values are equal (according to the debugger), but when `viewDidAppear(...)` is called the vales are changed. I don't know what else is being called between these two but for now this works.